# Place image on picture taken by camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to place png file on image taken by the app using a library
https://github.com/natario1/CameraView
Any ideas?

Comment: provide some code snippet, how you are using this library

Comment: first you have to save it , than you have to load it from the file

Answer (score 1):

you will get bitmap from this code from `onPictureTaken`

```
pictureResult.toBitmap(1000, 1000, new BitmapCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onBitmapReady(Bitmap bitmap) {
                //here bitmap you will get
            }
        });
```

from the bitmap you can convert png file

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos);
bitmapData = bos.toByteArray();

File f = new File(getCacheDir(), "temp.png");
try {
   boolean newFile = f.createNewFile();

   if (newFile) {
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
       fos.write(bitmapData);
       fos.flush();
       fos.close();
   }

} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
```

}